# How can I fetch google calendar tasks in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, google-tasks-api

I want to retrieving Google Tasks for this first i try to get it from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client from gdata i use calendar API but it gives me only calendar events.

Then I try to get it from http://code.google.com/apis/tasks but this API link only give me methods name it cannot give Google Task API.

Is there any API for getting Google Tasks, please provide me link of that.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: how are you accessing the data right now?

Comment: @Shaharyar I cannot get data from Google Task API. I use this link http://code.google.com/apis/tasks but this cannot gives me Google Tasks of my account.

Comment: @Anderson did u get any solution??

Answer (score 2):

Google is moving from older XML APIs ("Google Data APIs") to newer JSON APIs.

Google Calendar is still available as an XML API, and can be accessed with the older library, http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Google Tasks is available as a JSON API, and can be accessed with the newer library, http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

The libraries share some common components for networking and authorization, and are compatible.

Comment: under http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client i cannot found any API in download tab.

Comment: To get the library, use the svn checkout command shown on the Source Checkout page

Answer (score 0):

There is a tasks example for the `google-api-objectivec-client` at:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FTasksSample

Did not use it myself, only know of its existence...

Comment: this link cannot provide Google Task API. It only shows methods names.